# Why do the children not cry when they are taken from their homes?

Tags: realism, the-handmaids-tale

Some spoilers may be found ahead

At the end of season three, when the kids are walking to the plane, it appears to me as weird that none of the kids are crying or protesting, because they were kidnapped and some taken against their will and from their houses.

I like the scene, but thinking that is not real doesn't let me enjoy it.

Comment: I'll see if I can find comments from any of the EP's, but most of these kids were taken from their real families once already (and some may remember whom their real family is)--and if Hannah is any indication, they seem to form bonds with their Marthas, whom act like nannies (see scene when Fred and Serena visit Winslow household), so there may also be a lot trust there as well. There is one scene in season 4 where a boy doesn't bond with his former family, unless Rita (a Martha) makes him "Martha" food and it's used as a transitional psychological tool back into none-Gilead life.

Comment: One thing about kids is they don’t always know that what they are experiencing isn’t right. Certainly below 12 or so, most kids have a tendency to recognize any adult as an authority. So they might not have thought anything bad was happening to them.